# Java Socket auto close itself after File transfer

Tags: java, file, sockets

Im trying to transfer a file using java and sockets. My problem is that after the successfull file transfer the socket closes itself at the server side(where i transfer the file) .

Here is my server where i try to send the file

```
public void send_file_to_client(String requested_file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {

            File FILE_TO_SEND = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".wav");
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) FILE_TO_SEND.length()];

            fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_TO_SEND);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os = connsock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + "bytes)");
            toClient.writeUTF(Integer.toString(mybytearray.length));
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the client where i receive the file

```
public static void receive_file(String requested_file) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        try {

            File file_to_save = new File("C:\\ClientMusicStorage\\" + requested_file + ".wav");
            int bytesRead;

            String fileSize = fromServer.readUTF();
            int final_file_size = Integer.parseInt(fileSize);

            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[final_file_size];
            InputStream is = newclientSocket.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file_to_save);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            // bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            // current = bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            bos.flush();
            System.out.println("File " + requested_file + ".wav" + " downloaded (" + final_file_size + " bytes read)");
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            //eof - no error in this case
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //something went wrong
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what i get after the file transfer

```
SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:337)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried ***skipping*** that little bit which says `os.close();` ?

Comment: yep, if i remove this my transfer stucks at receiving bytes at the client side

Comment: and, have you then tried closing the socket (from the server side) in order to end the transfer?

Comment: i dont want to close the socket because i continue my programm after file transfer

Comment: Closing the streams effectively closes the socket. Any internet program should be able to deal with closed sockets.

Comment: Is that because you wrote `os.close();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically because you are closing the output stream (Part of your finally block) as soon you are done with the transfer. But the client code is still trying to read data from the stream, refer to the below portion of the code

```
 while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0)
```

so if you address this part you won't run into this issue. Basically from the server you can send the size of the file to the client followed by the contents of the file . Then in client side you can just read the file size first and read the next bytes, You just have to replace while loop with below line.

```
int fileReadBytes = is.read(mybytearray, 0, final_file_size);
```

Comment: The last part is wrong, it (probably) won't read the whole file.

Comment: i also think the last part wont read the whole file

Answer (score 0):

The `while ((bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0)` clause on the client will keep trying to read from the socket until the socket is closed, ***and*** will fail in the way you have observed once the socket is closed. So, that won't do.

Instead of doing that, you need to keep trying to read only for as long as the total number of bytes read so far is less than the total size of the file, which, as I can see, you have already communicated, so the client knows exactly how many bytes to read.  Once the entire file has been read, you exit from that loop on the client and proceed with the rest of the communication.

There is no need to close any input or output streams on either the server side or the client side.  When all communication is complete, you can just close the sockets.

Comment: if i dont close the streams my transfer stucks at receiving bytes at the client side

Comment: And if you do as my answer says, your transfer will not stucks.

Comment: your answer makes sense but it still stucks at receiving the bytes:(